# Overwrite lot of columns with mutate_at in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Given the following `dataframe` I am trying to mutate all but `c` and `d` columns using `dplyr::mutate_at` with `lambda` function but without luck:

```
structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(43, 2, -1), c = c(234242, 
-223, 1), d = c(1, 1, 2)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df %>% mutate_at(vars(-c("c", "d"), funs(x = x + rnorm(1, mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))
```

I want to overwrite the existing a and b columns without the need to mutate each other manually.
Please advise.

NOTE: My real dataset is similar but it has 50 columns to mutate and add this normal distribution random variable value. I want to automate it except for specific columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were nearly there. Two little things to change:

1. Change `x` to `.`
2. Access the column names without quote marks: `-c(c, d)` instead of `-c("c", "d")`.

This leads to

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(-c(c, d)), funs(. + rnorm(1, mean = mean(.), sd = sd(.))))
```

which works fine. Output is:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
      a     b       c     d
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1  3.05  56.6  234242     1
2  4.05  15.6    -223     1
3  5.05  12.6       1     2
```

Comment: there was even another mistake: you did not close the parentheses vars( ->)<-

Comment: It's a typo here, sorry @AndreElrico

Comment: @AndreElrico why should I delete the quotes?

Comment: @steves the answer is the same answer to: Why `mean()` is not called `calculate_the_mean()`. Its simply shorter and easier to type colnames without `"`

Comment: Its a style-decision the `tidyverse` took.

Comment: Some functions do require the quotes, that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 3):

Just as a side note:

You could use: `mutate_if`

```
df1 %>% mutate_if(names(.)%in%c("a","b"), funs(. + rnorm(1, mean = mean(.), sd = sd(.))))
```

There, of course, you have to use `"` because you're comparing strings with each other.

Answer (score 1):

If all the variables you want to change are in order, you can index them in `vars`. And you'll want to change x to "."

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(a:b), funs(. + rnorm(1, mean = mean(.), sd = sd(.))))
#       a      b       c     d
# 1  3.20  34.2   234242     1
# 2  4.20  -6.85    -223     1
# 3  5.20  -9.85       1     2
```

Comment: I have done this already, but the situation is that they aren't ordered in a way that I can use a:b but they are spread along the dataframe. I want to exclude the ones that I don't want to touch and mutate the others according to the above way.

Comment: Do they have a common name element?

Comment: Nope they don't